# How to run a batch file before running a Run/Debug configuration?

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to run a batch file that sets up an environment before I start debugging in PyCharm.

I created a Shell Script configuration that runs the batch file. It runs without any problem, but when I run the batch file configuration as a "Before launch" from the python script configuration that I need to debug, It get an error saying "Error running 'tabenv': Executable is not specified".

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: One way to do this is adding a `before launch` job in `Run/Debug Configurations`. You can setup your script as an external tool.

Comment: Are you running the batch from cmd line or double clicking from the file explorer?  If from file explorer, make sure you set up PATH and PYTHONPATH.